# @User.Identity.Name is empty in _Layout.chstml / Windows Auth appears to not work when hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, razor-pages

Using a very basic dotnetcore2 ef razor pages app, when I am on my development machine, @User.Identity.Name in _Layout.cshmtl works without issue. When I put that code up on my server using IIS, @User.Identity.Name refuses to be anything but empty despite my best attempts.

I've spent hours searching online and trying everything I can find and cant get over this problem.

These things that seem to work for everyone else...

- Make sure IIS has Windows auth enabled and anon auth disabled
- Make sure the app properties has Windows auth enabled and anon auth
  disabled
- Make sure the forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" property is set in web.config
- Register IIS Authentication service:services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); to startup.cs

...and yet @User.Identity.Name is always empty for me in _Layout.chsmtl when up on the server using IIS.

Here are the contents of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="f:\wwwroot\App\stdout.log" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

... the contents of my Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Title goes here</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header col-md-1">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="settingsbutton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Change User Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Contact Admin</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-page="Create"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Create New Records</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-controller="Request" asp-action="Index"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Return to Queue</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="headertext">Header</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <p class="nav adsusertext navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @User.Identity.Name</p>
            </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

...the contents of my Startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Foo.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Foo.Pages.Request;

namespace Foo
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //Register MVC using /Pages/Request razor page as the default start folder
            services.AddMvc()
              .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
              {
                  options.RootDirectory = "/Pages/Request";
              });;

            //Register the dbcontext
            services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("db"), b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));

            //Register IIS authentication services
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            }
    }
}
```

...and the contents of my Program.cs if it matters:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Foo.Models;
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;


namespace Foo
{

    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);
              host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseIISIntegration() 
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }

}
```

This is driving me nuts and if anyone has any ideas they would be much appreciated!!!!

Comment: Please take a minute and read [What are tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and how to use them and why you should avoid stuffing the title with tags. It won't make your question get answered any faster.

Comment: User name should be passed from controller to view if I were you.

Comment: `app.UseAuthentication()` should come before `app.UseMvc()`.

Comment: @Tseng Thanks. Will not tag titles anymore.

Comment: @Brad Gave it a go, and it didn't work. There's probably a reason why you suggested to move it there however, so i'm keeping it there! Thanks :D